# Building with dependencies from a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, deployment

I've got a Maven project in NetBeans with various dependencies that allow me to plot some 3D charts/graphs (JOGL, Gluegen & JZY3D). These work fine if I run the project from NetBeans, but when I build the project into a JAR file, I get the following...

```
Exception in thread "Building 3D Scatter Plot" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:442)
```

Is this an issue with Maven/NetBeans not building the JAR with all the correct dependencies or have I missed something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it is searching for a dll (gluegen-rt.dll), which should be in the java library path.

You could add a dll dependency (you'll need to manually add it in your repo or Nexus):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>gluegen-rt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluegen-rt</artifactId>
    <type>dll</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

For dependencies on native libraries, the library must be in your `PATH` or listed in the `java.library.path` system property. You can pass that as an argument to java process like this: `java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir`

I think you might be missing this part when doing outside Netbeans.

Comment: Update: So I've moved gluegen-rt.jar and it's native versions (the jar I'm assuming that's the file it's looking for) to /lib in the same folder as my JAR file then I use the following command (and still get the same error) 

java -Djava.library.path=/lib -jar application.jar

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-Djava.library.path=./lib` after placing your gluegen-rt.so (or dll for windows) library alongside application jar.

Comment: Tried that, still nothing :(

Comment: Are you still getting the same error i.e. "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path" after placing .so/dll in the `java.library.path`?